# Not able to export MongoDb data into local

Tags: mongodb, migration, mongodump, mongoexport

I am trying to export mongodb data from my server to local drive using `mongodump` or `mongoexport` but not able to do it properly.

I have tried these command:-

```
mongodump --host myhost:myport --db serverdb -u kousik -p 1234 -o C:\dump\data
```

and

```
mongoexport -h myhost:myport -u kousik -p 1234 -d serverdb -c mycollection -o C:\dump\data
```

I am getting this error:-

```
connected to: myhost:myport
Thu Jul 17 13:26:16.001 recv(): message len 759714643 is too large. Max is 48000000
Thu Jul 17 13:26:16.005 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
assertion: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 
myhost:myport ns:serverdb .$cmd query: { getnonce: 1 }
```

what is going wrong?

Comment: Facing the same problem. Any updates on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

mongoexport -ukousik -p1234 --host myhost --db serverdb --collection mycollection --query '{"column1":"value1", "column2":"value2"}' --csv --out test.csv --fields column1,column2,column3,column4